# Remove SVN checkout

Tags: svn

I accidentally put a checkout in the root of my drive, not in a sub directory.
Normally to remove an SVN checkout I just delete the directory in which I created the checkout.

Since this is now my complete drive, I cannot do this.
Is there another way to remove a checkout?

In windows explorer, I now see that my drive is versioned, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the directory you accidentally checked out to there will be a hidden `.svn` directory that you can delete.  This will return it to a normal directory which you can clean up.

You will need to [show hidden files](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-vista/) in order to see the `.svn` directory.